# Fixed menu with achors to wrong position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page with an anchor menu under the banner. When you click on any one of the links, it scrolls down to the right section but if you click on the same link it changes its position (minus 57px). How can I get the right position from the start after the page has loaded?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var top = $('#anchor-menu').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= top) {
        $('#anchor-menu').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        $('#anchor-menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
$('#menu-anchor-menu li').each(function(){
    var hash = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var tag = hash.split('#');
    $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pos = $('#'+tag[1]).offset().top - $('#anchor-menu').height();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: pos
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        $('#menu-anchor-menu li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening is:

1. Click event happens you grab the height before the fixed class has been applied so you miscalculate the height.
2. Your scroll to animate code fires
3. Your scroll event fires and adds the fixed class
4. You scroll to the wrong top.

The fix is to either "check" for the logic that is in the scroll event when the click event happens, or some other magical way to prevent the above steps from happening.  A solution is below i don't know if its the best one.

```
$(document)
  .ready(documentReady);

function checkScroll() {
  var $menu = $('#anchor-menu');
  var top = $menu.offset().top,
            y = $menu.scrollTop();
  if (y >= top) {
    $menu.addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $menu.removeClass('fixed');
  }
}

function documentReady() {
  $(window)
    .scroll(checkScroll);

  $('#menu-anchor-menu li')
     .each(forEachLi);

  function forEachLi() {
    checkScroll();

    var hash = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var tag = hash.split('#');
    $(this).find('a').click(anchorClicked);

    function anchorClicked(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var pos = $('#' + tag[1]).offset().top - $('#anchor-menu').height();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: pos
      }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
      $('#menu-anchor-menu li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Nix! here is a link to the page i'm referring to: http://www.stalwil.com/insperity/ if you click on contact us it scrolls down fine...but if you click on another link and then contact us again...it scrolls down to a different position

Comment: That sounds different then your description above.  So you are saying its not just clicking the same link thats broken, its basically once you click a link, ui scrolls, click a different link, ui scrolls, when you go back and click the original one its now off?

Comment: It looks like the first scroll is off.  It does not have enough offset at the top.  But the scrolls from one area to the next is correct it has an offset.  Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks nix! I'll check it out when I get home.